# Find the matrix $[T]$ with respect to the given basis, where $T$ is defined as $T:\mathcal{V}_2 \rightarrow \mathcal{V}_3$ by $Tv(x)=\int_0^x v(t)dt$

Tags: linear-algebra

The information given to me is that $\mathcal{V_n}$ is the vector space of real polynomials of degree $\leq n$ and that the basis if given by $v_i(t)=t^{i-1}.$ $T$ is defined as $T:\mathcal{V}_2 \rightarrow \mathcal{V}_3$ by $Tv(x)=\int_0^x v(t)dt$, and part of the question asks me to find the matrix $[T]$ with respect to the given basis. This is what I've done so far, but I feel like I am headed in the wrong direction:

With the definition of the basis they have given me, $\beta_2=\{1,t,t^2\}$ and I call $1=v_1, t=v_2,t^2=v_3$. This is what I think I am supposed to do next: 
$$\int_0^xv_1dt=\int_0^x1dt=x\\\int_0^xv_2dt=\int_0^xtdt=\frac{1}{2}x^2\\\int_0^xv_3dt=\int_0^xt^2dt=\frac{1}{3}x^3$$ but now I don't know what to do with my results. I think I am supposed to now write them in terms of the basis of $\mathcal V_3$ which I can write as $\beta_3=\{1, x, x^2, x^3\}$ so then I will have:
$$\int_0^xv_1dt=\int_0^x1dt=x\color{red}{=0(1)+1(x)+0(x^2)+0(x^3)}\\\int_0^xv_2dt=\int_0^xtdt=\frac{1}{2}x^2\color{red}{=0(1)+0(x)+\frac{1}{2}(x^2)+0(x^3)}\\\int_0^xv_3dt=\int_0^xt^2dt=\frac{1}{3}x^3\color{red}{=0(1)+0(x)+0(x^2)+\frac{1}{3}(x^3)}$$ which will give me the matrix $[T]=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&\frac{1}{2}&0\\0&0&\frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}$. I really have no idea if I am making huge mistakes or not. I don't want an answer as it is a homework question, but any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Correct answer!

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane really? Thanks a bunch for the quick check!

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments, the answer is correct.

(I have not checked it myself, I'm only answering to get off the unanswered queue.)